# What does "warning: nm: no name list" mean?

Tags: linux, macos

I'm trying to grep for a symbol in a library.

```
$ nm /usr/local/ssl/macosx-x64/lib/libcrypto.a | grep rc4_md5_enc
warning: nm: no name list
warning: nm: no name list
warning: nm: no name list
...
```

The [GNU nm man page](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/nm.html) does not appear to discuss the condition or the output.

What does *`warning: nm: no name list`* mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [manual page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/nm.1.html) for `nm`, the "name list" means "symbol table".  If you are running this command on Linux, and the file is (as implied by its path) for OSX, then the format of the binary file is likely incompatible.  For instance, if you use

```
file /usr/local/ssl/macosx-x64/lib/libcrypto.a
```

it may tell you that it is a "current archive".  But other tools may not deal well with files from another type of system.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting. An archive is just a collection of object files, and `nm` works with object files. The man page makes that clear because it describes the command as *"... lists the symbols from object files ..."*